# A package for the DOM - Events

Tags: javascript

Please provide feedback on the correctness of this code.  It should handle older versions of IE but how far back it goes I have not determined yet.

```
/**************************************************************************************************
EVENTS
*/

    // ... snip

    Priv.functionNull = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    // createEvent
    Priv.createEvent = function () {
        if (doc.createEvent) {
            return function (type) {
                var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                event.initEvent(type, true, false);
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.dispatchEvent(event);
                });
            };
        }
        if (doc.createEventObject) {
            return function (type) {
                var event = doc.createEventObject();
                event.eventType = type;
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.fireEvent('on' + type, event);
                });
            };
        }
        return Priv.functionNull;
    };

    Priv.proto.createEvent = function (type) {
        return Priv.createEvent.call(this, type);
    };

    Pub.createEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            Priv.createEvent.call(temp, type);
        };
    }());

    // addEvent
    Priv.addEvent = (function () {
        if (win.addEventListener) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.addEventListener(type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        if (win.attachEvent) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        return Priv.functionNull;
    }());

    Priv.proto.addEvent = function (type, callback) {
        return Priv.addEvent.call(this, type, callback);
    };

    Pub.addEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type, callback) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            Priv.addEvent.call(temp, type, callback);
        };
    }());

    //remove event
    Priv.proto.removeEvent = (function () {
        if (win.removeEventListener) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.removeEventListener(type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        if (win.detachEvent) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.detachEvent('on' + type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        return Priv.functionNull;
    }());

    Priv.proto.removeEvent = function (type, callback) {
        return Priv.removeEvent.call(this, type, callback);
    };

    Pub.removeEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type, callback) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            Priv.removeEvent.call(temp, type, callback);
        };
    }());
```

Answer (score 1):

**The good**

Your code will handle any type of browser, is pretty easy to follow.

**The bad**

`Pub.removeEvent` will not work. That's because you define `Priv.proto.removeEvent` twice, whereas you probably want to define `Priv.proto.removeEvent` and `Priv.removeEvent`.

**The ugly**

You are using `doc.createEvent` which is deprecated, you should look into [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

**Furthermore**

Because IE decided to do things differently for many event related things, a lot of people check as you do for the existence of a function and go from there, however your approach could be a little DRYer.

```
Priv.addEvent = (function () {
    if (win.addEventListener) {
        return function (type, callback) {
            $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                val.addEventListener(type, callback);
            });
        };
    }
    if (win.attachEvent) {
        return function (type, callback) {
            $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
                val.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
            });
        };
    }
    return Priv.functionNull;
}());
```

can be done as

```
Priv.addEvent = (function () {
  var addFunction = win.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent',
      prefix      = win.addEventListener ? '' : 'on';

  return function (type, callback) {
    $A.someKey(this, function (val) {
      val[addFunction]( prefix + type, callback);
    });
  };
  return Priv.functionNull;
}());
```

This approach can be applied to `addEvent`, `removeEvent` and perhaps to 'createEvent'.

Finally, as always, you should steer away from `someKey`, just stick to the standard `Array`.

Comment: "The good, The Bad, The Ugly and IE." Definately the right order.